# Accented characters appear weird (have their accents displayed after the character) after pasting

Tags: fonts, non-ascii-characters

Not sure if this is the appropriate place to ask or doctype, but i'm gonna ask anyway...
Been working with a german client, and this very wierd problem started showing up..

So while populating the content for the website,  I copy/paste from their pdf sheet into my editor (Espresso). The wierd thing is while all the text looks pristine on the editor, upon opening in the browser, we start getting wierd anomalies with the accented character's accents, being pushed forward. So a ' Ö '  shows up as O" , and so on.

I thought it was some unicode problem, but the site is declared as utf8 , and there is no rich text or anything being entered, its just raw text from the editor. So it is really mind boggling. If the client edits the files directly, its appears correctly. And I found out if I type and replace the accented characters manually, it's fine too.

Anyone had similar experiences / solutions ?

I'd have though there shouldn't be a localization/font problem since these are essentially latin characters ? (correct me if i'm wrong)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reliably cut and paste from a PDF.  The internal format is not as it appears. :-)

PDFs may use special encodings internally to make the printed page look correct, but that does not mean that you can copy paste.

Here is a StackExchange question that has a *little* bit of background: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22213/how-to-get-accented-unicode-characters-that-can-be-copy-pasted.

While it's not quite the same question as yours, it does show that how you make the PDF does matter.  It is possible that some Latin-1 (accented) characters are encoded within the PDF not as characters with the expected Unicode codepoint(s) but with drawing instructions to make the character appear correctly.

Perhaps [this product](http://www.e-pdfconverter.com/pdf-to-text/help.htm) can help you. I have not used it, so cannot recommend it, but a little searching may yield something you can use.  (This one claims to support German.)

Comment: You can't reliably cut and paste from **some** PDF files. The PDF format *does* support storing the text in a way that's perfectly well suited for copy-and-paste (including "strange" characters). Unfortunately not all PDF files out there actually *use* these features (or use them correctly).

Comment: I assumed that if you cut and paste from whatever richtext format (word/pdf/etc) into a code editor, it'd automatically turn the text into raw non-format-dependant text wouldn't it ? How should one 'extract' the text out from a pdf for web usage ?

Comment: For some strange reason PDF files produced with Latex have a tendency of using composed umlauts instead of "real" ones.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input. :) This was truly mind boggling.

Comment: @Wintertrain It would be nice if clipboards could figure this out; I suspect they don't because it is a special format after all.  Still, I suppose they could convert composed characters....

Comment: yes part of the reason why it was mind boggling was because if I copied a 'proper' accented character, and did a Find in the document, the 'fake' accented characters would still match it. So there definitely is some high level problem here.

Comment: Ah yes, but _the PDF reader_ can find characters properly because it _knows_ its own encodings of these things!  Forcing clipboards and editors to know all the details of Adobe's PDF and anticipate future changes that Adobe might make is too much to ask!  (Hope that clears some things up.)

Comment: @Ray: then again: if the PDF reader knows about the encoding and how to interpret it: why doesn't it put the correctly converted stuff on the clipboard in the first place?

Comment: the wierd thing is if you do a search for the 'pdf accented character' in the code editor containing a mixture of 'proper' and 'pdf' accented characters, they would all match.

Comment: +1 @Joachim, Excellent point; I didn't think of that.  Maybe the authors of Acrobat Reader didn't either? That would be a great SO question. I've seen a lot of crud go on the clipboard when trying to copy-paste -- fancy frames for example give some strange characters on the clipboard.  It does appear that the reader is written to compensate on search but not on copy.  I can only guess at the reason.